# ISO_IR 58 support in .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, dicom

There is a double byte character set in DICOM named ISO_IR 58. As far as I can tell the equivalent encoding for this in .Net is gb2312. I am trying to encode ISO_IR 58 characters in 7 bit ASCII for communication between medical systems.

In the java world the string gb2312 works to do this encoding.

First look at this example for ISO_IR 87 (ISO_IR 87 equals iso-2022-jp in .Net):

```
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-2022-jp");
byte[] bytes = enc.GetBytes("叙収參参^去厰厦厘=却占^卮博南");
string asciistring = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```

This takes the input string and gives the ASCII string: $B=v<}RT;2(B^$B5nRRRONR(B=$B5Q@j(B^$BRHGnFn(B

with all proper escape sequences with which I can use correctly.

(the actual first escape character does not display here but the rest of the sequence does when pasted)

If I use this code with characters from ISR_IR 58:

```
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("gb2312");
byte[] bytes = enc.GetBytes("ㄆㄉㄊㄋ^ㄌㄍㄐㄓ^ㄖㄠㄢㄤ");
string asciistring = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```

I only get the string: ????????^????????^????????

So what is the answer to DICOM ISO_IR 58 encoding using .Net? Am I using the wrong string for encoding? Is ISO_IR 58 in DICOM not supported in .Net? Is there a bug in .Net? Is it even possible?

Comment: what is the output in Java for the second sample?

Comment: In java returned is this string for the same characters: $)A¨Æ¨É¨Ê¨Ë(B^$)A¨Ì¨Í¨Ð¨Ó(B^$)A¨Ö¨à¨â¨ä(B     again the actual first esc character, usually represented by a arrow is not seen in the paste here from the string.

Comment: How are you examining the resulting `asciistring`? In debug, save to a text file, on the screen, etc??? When you use Java and get the correct results, do you use it on the same computer?

Comment: @Ulugbek I am not a java developer, I use .Net. But where I work our product is build in java. I test it using .Net. I will ask for the equivalent code in java with encoded ISO_IR 58 correctly and add it here. I am really interested in this answer since nothing I seem to do in .Net works, and Clear Canvas seems to have not supported only this specific character set in the DICOM standard for whatever reason.   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ClearCanvas/ClearCanvas/master/Dicom/SpecificCharacterSetParser.cs

Comment: @ Racil Hilan It is more complicated that that, I am using Clear Canvas DICOM toolkit do perform DICOM C-Finds, and display results of the information received in a data grid on a windows form. For an example see: https://github.com/ClearCanvas/ClearCanvas/issues/147

Comment: What I would ultimately like to achieve is to is see if this is possible in .Net, and if so I want I write it myself and submit it for Clear Canvas to be able to support this character set and give back to this absolutely amazing open source repository.

Comment: In the [link that you provided above](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ClearCanvas/ClearCanvas/master/Dicom/SpecificCharacterSetParser.cs), there is a list of encodings. I don't see the **GB2312** or **ISO-IR 58**. The only encoding there is **GB18030**. Have you tried that? See my answer for a full research.

Comment: But the string returned from Java is not 7-bit ASCII, it is 8-bit string. To get such output you have to do `string asciistring = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetString(bytes);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASCIIEncoding is an 7-bit encoding and any 8-bit encoding cannot be 
represented with it.  Hence the question marks.

This should work for all the charsets:

```
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("gb2312");
byte[] bytes = enc.GetBytes("ㄆㄉㄊㄋ^ㄌㄍㄐㄓ^ㄖㄠㄢㄤ");

Encoding asc = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
string astr = asc.GetString(bytes);
```

Output

```
A8 C6 A8 C9 A8 CA A8 CB 5E A8 CC A8 CD A8 D0 A8 D3 5E A8 D6 A8 E0 A8 E2 A8 E4 
¨Æ¨É¨Ê¨Ë^¨Ì¨Í¨Ð¨Ó^¨Ö¨à¨â¨ä
```

Comment: Very good point indeed. What made miss that is the fact that the his first example works, but now that I'm thinking about it, although the **iso-2022-jp** is 8-bit but it was designed to be able to be encoded in 7-bit without a loss (according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_2022)). I tested your code with the following encodings: **gb2312**, **ISO-IR-58**, **GB18030**, **GB_2312-80**. They all returned the exact same result that you have in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Doing some research on the encoding, according to [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml) the **ISO-IR-58** is mapped to **GB_2312-80** not to **GB2312**, which in [.Net Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx) is mapped to **x-cp20936** with the code page **20936**. If that's the case, you need to use:

```
Encoding.GetEncoding("x-cp20936");
```

or

```
Encoding.GetEncoding(20936);
```

Of course, both are identical, so it's up to you whether you like to use the name or code page.

---

You mentioned that Java worked fine with **GB2312**, which you thought was the correct mapping for **ISO-IR-58**. Now, that's really interesting. The funny thing is that according to [DICOM](ftp://medical.nema.org/medical/dicom/final/cp1234_ft.doc) (this link is for MS Word document), **ISO_IR 58** was mapped to IANA **ISO-2022-CN**. This conflicts with what IANA says, so who to believe? OK, we followed IAIA above and I hope that will work for you, but let's follow DICOM now and see where it goes. Sadly, there is no **ISO-2022-CN** encoding in .Net, so we need a bit more research.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_2022), the **ISO-2022-CN** encoding can start with one of the following:

> ESC $ ) A to switch to GB 2312-1980 (2 bytes per character) [designated to G1]
>   ESC $ ) G to switch to CNS 11643-1992 Plane 1 (2 bytes per character) [designated to G1]
>   ESC $ * H to switch to CNS 11643-1992 Plane 2 (2 bytes per character)

You mentioned that the correct string return by Java started with `ESC $ ) A`, so we'll follow the first option which leads to the [Wikipedia page for GB2312](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GB_2312), which is what you thought to be the correct encoding. Now here are several important things to observe on this page:

- It starts by saying **GB2312 (1980)**. Well, wait a second. Is that what **GB_2312-80** encoding actually mean? If yes, then we're back to what IANA told us in the first place and the above mentioned code is the way to go.
- Then it continues to say **has been superseded by GBK and GB18030**. Hmmm, .Net Framework does not have GBK encoding, but it does have **GB18030** with code page **54936**. I don't think it is what you should use, but it is worth a try if the other encodings did not work for you.
- Then if you scroll to the **Two implementations of GB2312** heading, you can see the following text:

> As of 2015, Microsoft .Net Framework is using Implementation A. iconv-1.14, php-5.6, ActivePerl-5.20, Java 1.7, Python 3.4 are using Implementation B.[2] Ruby 2.2 is compatible with both Implementation A and Implementation B, it internally converts the conflictive characters to Implementation A.

Did you read that? I will repeat: .Net Framework is using Implementation A and Java is using Implementation B.

Comment: I tried x-cp20936, and GB18030 and neither of them work correctly.

Comment: I found something funny. Despite that Microsoft page (which I referenced in my answer) did not mention it, it actually support the **ISO-IR-58** encoding. Wow! I checked the `WebName` for it, and it actually returned **GB2312**. So **ISO-IR-58** is actually mapped to **GB2312**. See my comment to codeDr answer for more test results.

Comment: Java and .NET only differ on how they map GB 2312's points to Unicode (they both use some sort of EUC-CN for "gb2312"), while the difference between ISO-2022 and EUC-CN is how they encode GB 2312's row-cell position into bytes.